# Authenticate client over RESTful API server built upon Java Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, rest, authentication

I am searching for the best approach of authenticating users of mobile clients when accessing my RESTful API. For example, how approximately AirBnb uses it's auth module.

Should the authentication be different for RESTful and basic session-based resource, working with the same data?

I am not a mobile developer therefore, I am interested in what is the best way to provide authentication from server-side, so the mobile-platform developers could use it simply.

I googled for few approaches using OAuth, OAuth2, HTTPBasic authentication and still wonder how the mobile developers can use such API, how they will store this token (cookie is stored by browser in browser-oriented apps).

Could you please suggest me some links/code samples/techiques that you used in production or pet-projects or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and manageable alternative to OAuth(2) for authentication is [JWT](http://jwt.io).

You don't need additional infrastructure, the workflow and use is straightforward and there are ready to use libraries for all major languages already available.

Compared to HTTP Basic Authentication [JWT](http://jwt.io) is more flexible by transmitting additional information not just credentials, you can store the [JWT](http://jwt.io) token as JSON or you can use cookies, you don't need to store the credentials on client side and you don't transmit the credentials on every request.

Also based on [JWT](http://jwt.io)  you can realize very easy a single sign on function. So if you need more than just a simple system user then you should definitely try [JWT](http://jwt.io).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But if I am going to start to support, for example OAuth, so the users will be able to authenticate on another services(just interested) what should I start from? I mean "use my service provider" when authenticating on another service?

Comment: @MaxKuzmentsov, Do you mean an authentication service like Google, Facebook, Yahoo etc. are providing?

Comment: Yes, something like that or GitHub, Airbnb etc.

Comment: In first place this has nothing to do using OAuth(2) or not. Some of them are based on OAuth2 but it's also possible to build such a service without using it. How a developer use the google sign in service you can read here https://developers.google.com/identity/. I guess this can be a good starting point to see which interaction between client and server is needed. Also take a look at JWT introduction to see the client server interaction..